# Transfered from Chrome OS to Ubuntu, is on Version 16.04, don't know how to update

Tags: 16.04, chromeos

I tried to follow the instructions, but quickly I realized that I do not have a update manager as I installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook with Chrome OS. I have no idea how to be on version 18.04 or 20.04 as I am stuck on version 16.04.

Comment: Did you use the chromebooks linux function? In other words, you have a normal chromebook but you can also access terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade your Ubuntu version via terminal enter the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```